# $(this) na arrow function retorna elemento diferente

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Vejam que o `$(this)` em cada caso abaixo aponta para um elemento diferente:

**1º) Function:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("input").val(function(){ return $(this).val(); });
});      ↑                               ↑
         ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

**2º) Arrow function:**

```
      ↓¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯˥
$("button").click(function(){      ↓
    $("input").val(()=>{ return $(this).val(); });
});
```

Como fazer para que, no **2º caso**, o `$(this)` aponte para o mesmo elemento que aponta no **1º caso**, ou seja, o `input`?

Se para isso não devo usar o `$(this)`, como referenciar uma variável dentro da *arrow function* que selecione o `$("input")` em questão?

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, mas eu precisava mesmo era de uma resposta conclusiva.

Comment: De qualquer forma fica a dica para quem puder pesquisar (ou até mesmo dá uma olhada na documentação) e escrever algo mais elaborado. :)

Comment: Ah tah rs... valeu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse efeito que vê foi um dos motivadores para a criação das Arrow Functions.

Veja algumas citações da [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) em relação a esse efeito:

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value (...)
>
> An arrow function does not newly define its own `this` (...)
>
> Since arrow functions do not have their own `this` (...)
>
> No separate `this` (...)

Por estas citações vê que uma Arrow Function não define o seu próprio `this`. Em vez disso usa o do contexto na qual está inserida.

Torna-se muito util em vários cenários. Passo a citar um da própria documentação, ainda que adaptado:

```js
function Pessoa() {
  this.idade = 0;

  setInterval(function crescer() {
    this.idade++;
    console.log(`A idade é agora ${this.idade}`);
  }, 1000);
}

let p = new Pessoa();
```

Repare como o exemplo não funciona pois a função `crescer` define o seu próprio `this` que é diferente do de `Pessoa`. Por este motivo não consegue aceder à propriedade `idade`.

No entanto já irá funcionar com uma Arrow Function pois o `this` será o de `Pessoa`, que é o local onde ela está inserida:

```js
function Pessoa() {
  this.idade = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.idade++;
    console.log(`A idade é agora ${this.idade}`);
  }, 1000);
}

let p = new Pessoa();
```

**Concluindo**

Utilizando **JQuery e** uma **arrow function**, dentro dela **$(this) nunca irá funcionar**.

### Contornando o problema

Apesar de não funcionar diretamente com `$(this)` existem formas de contornar o problema

- Capturando o elemento selecionado numa variavel

  No código que apresentou consegue reproduzir o mesmo efeito guardando primeiramente o(s) elemento(s) obtido(s) com o seletor de `input` numa variável. Depois pode utiliza-la dentro da arrow function as vezes que quiser:

  ```
  $("button").click(function(){
      const input = $("input");
      input.val(()=>{ return input.val(); });
  });
  ```
- Utilizando [`event.currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

  Esta forma funciona quando o `$(this)` que se quer capturar vem de um evento, como por exemplo o de click. Infelizemente este não se enquadra no exemplo que tem na pergunta, ainda assim, deixo aqui como referencia.

  Nesse caso pode capturar também o objeto que representa o evento da ação, consegue obter o alvo do evento com `event.currentTarget`. Este alvo representa o elemento nativo de JS e por isso para ser utilizado como um objeto de JQuery tem de fazer `$(event.currentTarget)`.

  Exemplo:

```js
const coresDisponiveis = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'cyan'];
$("button").click((event) => {
    let novaCor = Math.floor(Math.random() * coresDisponiveis.length);
    $(event.currentTarget).css('background-color', coresDisponiveis[novaCor]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clique para trocar a cor</button>
```

Comment: Obg pela resposta. Resumindo, não tem como fazer o que a pergunta deseja?

Comment: @dvd Não tem como fazer diretamente. Resumindo o máximo possivel, não há como fazer `$(this)` funcionar dentro de uma array function com Jquery. Atualizei a resposta com mais informação em relação a isso.